# want to update my ListView after Delete in RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Actually it's my first time to use the RecyclerView and i try to delete the item from the list View as the user Click the Delete Button from the menuItem....
But after click on the Delete option my item is Delete on my Database but my adapter is not updated...
Help me how i set my Adapter

**My code:**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
public static final String DELETE_URL = "http://delete.php";
String KEY_UNIQUE_ID="id";
Context context;

List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter;

ImageLoader imageLoader1;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<GetDataAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){

    super();
    this.getDataAdapter = getDataAdapter;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder Viewholder, final int position) {

    final GetDataAdapter getDataAdapter1 =  getDataAdapter.get(position);

    imageLoader1 = ServerImageParseAdapter.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();

    imageLoader1.get(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(),
            ImageLoader.getImageListener(
                    Viewholder.CircularNetworkImageView,//Server Image
                    R.drawable.loading,//Before loading server image the default showing image.
                    R.drawable.loading //Error image if requested image dose not found on server.
            )
    );

    Viewholder.CircularNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(getDataAdapter1.getImageServerUrl(), imageLoader1);

    Viewholder.ImageTitleNameView.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageTitleName());
    Viewholder.UserAge.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageAge());
    Viewholder.User_Gender.setText(getDataAdapter1.getImageGender());
    Viewholder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPopupMenu(Viewholder.overflow,getDataAdapter1.getId());

        }
    });

}
/**
 * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
 */
private void showPopupMenu(View view, String position) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_album, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener(position));
  //  Toast.makeText(context, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    popup.show();
}

/**
 * Click listener for popup menu items
 */
class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    private String position;
    public MyMenuItemClickListener(String position) {
        this.position=position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.Delete:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Delete option"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                delete(position);
                           return true;
            case R.id.Edit_Option:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Edit option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
        }
        return false;
    }

}
private void delete(String id){
    //http call for Delete the item and it's successfully work but my list is not updated
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return getDataAdapter.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView ImageTitleNameView,UserAge,User_Gender;
    public ImageView overflow;
    public Parse.CircularNetworkImageView CircularNetworkImageView ;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        ImageTitleNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_item);
        UserAge=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        User_Gender =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        overflow = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.overflow);

        CircularNetworkImageView = (CircularNetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.VollyNetworkImageView1);

    }
}
```

Comment: after deleting item, delete that item from your model and add adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

Comment: because your delete method is empty ...

Comment: @Selvin actually sir i delete the delete method code but it work correctly

Comment: @Divyesh Sir i add getDataAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position) after calling the delete method

Comment: notifyItemRemoved is not removing ... you need to remove it by yourself ... as he wrote in his comment

Comment: @Selvin sir after Delete my list is not updated means the Deleted item is showing in the list

Comment: can you post your code which you write in success of network call

Comment: @user3333848 sure

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40652661/6747577)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First change this:

```
Viewholder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPopupMenu(Viewholder.overflow,position);

        }
    });
```

Then change this method:

```
private void showPopupMenu(View view, int position) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_album, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener(position));
  //  Toast.makeText(context, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    popup.show();
}
```

Now, inside menuitemClickListener method change this :

```
private int position;
public MyMenuItemClickListener(int position) {
        this.position=position;
    }
```

Finally, chnage this method:

```
private void delete(int id){
    //http call for Delete the item and it's successfully work but my list is not updated
    getDataAdapter.remove(id);
    notifyItemRemoved(id);

}
```

Comment: i got it sir bt how can i know which item i have to delete without passing the **getDataAdapter1.getId()** to the delete method

Comment: you do not need to pass getDataAdapter1.getId(). just pass position or getAdapterPosition()

Comment: i did it as u guide me bt after that app crash problem is arise

Comment: it works bt now my item is not delete from the database

Comment: when you store your item in database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129792/discussion-between-techdigi-and-divyesh).

Answer (score 1):

just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and remove that item from arraylist or list!